# Is there any Inference engine for CNN on Vivante GC2000 GPU with OpenCL 1.1 EP?

Tags: deep-learning, opencl, conv-neural-network, gpgpu, imx6

I have iMX6 quad, consists of Vivante GC2000 GPU provides OpenCL 1.1 EP implementation. I have a **trained Convolution neural network model** that I just want to run on iMX6-GPU with **OpenCL 1.1 EP**. I have tried to cross-compile TensorFlow for it, but it's not working. I want to know if there is any `Open Source project or any commuunity` available that provides inference engine to run **CNN on OpenCL 1.1 EP**.

Comment: I am also looking for the same solution. Could someone throw few insights?